# Jpa createSQLQuery returns List<Object> instead of List<Employee>

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, dao

Trying to make an sql query to get as a result a list of Class "EmployeeCardOrderLink". But this code always returns me an list of Object. Casts doesn't working. I got the right data in this list, but it's just object. In debug i can call methods(Idea suggest according interface of my class), but then i got "class Object doesn't have a such method". And i can't use TypedQuery cause i have old JPA version, it doesn't support this.

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeCardOrderLinkDAOImpl extends AbstractBasicDAO<EmployeeCardOrderLink> implements EmployeeCardOrderLinkDAO {
 //....
@Override
    public List<EmployeeCardOrderLink> getLinksByOrderNumber(Integer num) {
     List<EmployeeCardOrderLink> result = (ArrayList<EmployeeCardOrderLink>) getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select * from employee_card_order_links " +
                "where trip_order_id = " +  num).list();
       return result;
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use Hibernate (not `JPA`), if you are using `Session`. Hibernate is `JPA` provider of course. You have to use `EntityManager` and other related things to use `JPA`.

You don't need SQL here. SQL always returns list of objects (if you don't use transformers to `DTO` objects).

Just use `HQL` (`JPQL` in `JPA`)

To get all `EmployeeCardOrderLink`

```
getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
    .createQuery("select link from EmployeeCardOrderLink link").list();
```

Query `"from EmployeeCardOrderLink"` will work for Hibernate too (for JPA will not work).